# replace values with variables - jq

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, jq

I can work out how to use jq to replace a value from a variable,

```
$ jq -n --arg name bar '{"name":$name}'

{
  "name": "bar"
}
```

But I am not sure how to replace multiple values.

```
{
  ...
  "snstopic": {
    "topic-project1": "team-project1-dev",
    "topci-project2": "team-project2-dev",
    ...  (different json files have different number of sns topics)
  },
 ...
}
```

I set these environment variables:

```
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
$ export AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=123456789012
$ export ARN_PREFIX="arn:aws:sns:${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:"
```

I want to get output as below

```
{
  ...
  "snstopic": {
    "topic-project1": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:team-project1-dev",
    "topci-project2": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:team-project2-dev",
    ...  (different json files have different number of sns topics
  },
 ...
}
```

How to add it in all matched keys in `.snstopic`?

Comment: Pipe the output of jq to jq processing one substitution at a time.

Comment: did `jq` has something as for-loop feature?

Comment: Don't know. I just use simple expression based cases.

Comment: I can replace one, but if there are 10 to 20, do you mean I have to write 10 of them? and the different json files have different number of topics.

Comment: For the simple case of change a couple of items, pipeling works fine. I don't know how to do global replace in your case using jq. I would then switch and use `sed` with a script file.

Comment: Sed to handle json file? can you show the real codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell: `map_values` is your friend.

Let's suppose your template is in the file template.json. Then the following script will perform the specified transformation:

```
#!/bin/bash
# As far as this example is concerned,
# there is no need to export any variables
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-2
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID=123456789012
ARN_PREFIX="arn:aws:sns:${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:"

jq --arg prefix "$ARN_PREFIX" '
  .snstopic |= map_values($prefix + .)
' template.json
```

### Example

template.json

```
{
  "snstopic": {
    "topic-project1": "team-project1-dev",
    "topci-project2": "team-project2-dev"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "snstopic": {
    "topic-project1": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:team-project1-dev",
    "topci-project2": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:123456789012:team-project2-dev"
  }
}
```

Comment: Really appreciated. the usage of `map_values` is super helpful.